# trying to solve project euler number 14

Tags: c++

I´m trying to solve project euler problem number 14 and i have the code almost ready, but it keeps me giving the wrong answer.. Why it doesn't count more steps?? Thanks, sorry for the lack of commentary..

```
#include <iostream>

int collatz_length(int number);

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int size_sequence, max_sequence = 0, number_ = 1000000, num;

    while (number_>1) {
        size_sequence = collatz_length(number_);
        if (size_sequence > max_sequence) {
            max_sequence = size_sequence;
            num = number_;
            cout << "size   " << size_sequence 
                << "   starting number   " << num << endl;

        }
        number_--;
    }
    cout << "The longest sequence has "
        << max_sequence << " steps, starting from the number: "  << num << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

int collatz_length(int number) {
    using namespace std;

    int size_sequence = 0;

    while (number > 1) {
        if ((number % 2) == 0){
            number /= 2;
        }
        else {
            number = (3 * number + 1);
        }
        size_sequence++;
    }

    return size_sequence;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that `3*n+1` will overflow an `int`. Perhaps you should use a `uint64_t`?